# Block traffic from specific IP at Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, ip-blocking

I have an Azure Cloud Service and I am getting a huge traffic from specific IP address. How can I block a traffic coming from specific IP address?
Is it possible to do this w/o re-deploying the service using portal configuration?

Comment: Did created a VNet for your cloud service?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for your scenario:

Solution 1: Open the firewall on your VM OS and Block the IP address by using the firewall.

Solution 2: If your cloud service is not deployed into a VNet, you can leverage NSG changing the **NetworkConfiguration** section of **CSCFG** file as in the example below:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>

    <VirtualNetworkSite name="VNet-BL"/>

    <AddressAssignments>

      <InstanceAddress roleName="WebRole">

        <Subnets>

          <Subnet name="TestSubnet-2"/>

        </Subnets>

      </InstanceAddress>

    </AddressAssignments>

    <NetworkSecurityGroupRefs>

      <NetworkSecurityGroupRef roleName="WebRole">

        <NetworkSecurityGroup name="BlockOutbound"/>

      </NetworkSecurityGroupRef>

    </NetworkSecurityGroupRefs>

  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

In the “NetworkSecurityGroupRefs” section, you can reference already existing NSGs, you cannot define new ones here: you have to create outside and using ASM APIs, ARM will not work here. Finally, please keep in mind that NSG is not compatible with Network/Endpoint ACLs.

Hope this helps!